# Matplotlib Axis Limits Change Plot to Plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a plot where I would like to save it as both a PNG and a PDF. The first time I save the figure, the limits are what I want them to be. After I plot it, the limits change, and the when I try to plot it a second time, the limits are different than my intent.

For example, if I save it as a PDF and then a PNG, the PDF will have the correct limits and the PNG will have incorrect (expanded limits).

```
>INFO:  Before Plotting Y Lims: 445210 to 445690
>INFO:  After Plot 1 Y Lims: 445175 to 445724
>INFO:  After Plot 2 Y Lims: 445091 to 445808
```

Anyone know what is causing this? I can work around it by catching the axes limits before the plot and re-applying them before the second plot, but that is clunky.

Comment: can you post your code that does the plotting

Comment: One moment, let me try and put together an MWE.

Comment: Unfortunately I have been unable to get together a MWE that gives the issue I am having. I also noticed that the PNG is missing two sets of markers than the PDF has. I will look around the code a bit more and update my packages to see if that helps.